# Can I use Firebase Realtime database/Firestore as a OAuth2.0 Server?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an native Android application using Firebase (No other custom server, only Firebase)
And it should use other services. (like Facebook API, Twitter API, etc...)

The service providers are providing the REST Api through OAuth 2.0.
I am very newbie of the OAuth 2.0, I have no knowledge, experience.

Yesterday I tried to implement "Implicit Grant", and it works fine.
I can get access_token, and I can use the REST APIs using it.

But there is a parameter "expires_in": 604800 (7 days).
This means my customer should re-authorize after 7 days. (There is no refresh_token.)

So I am considering to change the implement from "Implicit Grant" to "Authorization Code Grant".
But I already told you, I am newbie of the OAuth 2.0. (I have no experience, this is my first time.)

If I choose "Authorization Code Grant", I should store the "code" to exchange the "access_token".
Then where should I store it?
I think I can store it in local device, but it doesn't consider security.
So I want to know can I use "Firebase Realtime database/Firestore" as a storage to store "code".

I think it is reasonable.
But I am not sure...

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you are a newbie , it’s worth reading more about Oauth 2.0 especially when you want to build Oauth server , a simple google search returns 
https://stormpath.com/blog/what-the-heck-is-oauthhttps://stormpath.com/blog/what-the-heck-is-oauth

Fire base database alone enough to built a sever , you need endpoints to handle incoming request for you can use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

So if you want to implement **Authorisation Grant ** or Implicit Flow, it needs to happen in browser ,

1. First you can use cloud functions to handle the incoming GET request from client (in browser)
2. Then you return a login page where users can login,
3. Then handle the auth submit request from page , authenticate it , if valid generate a **code** or **access_token** (in case of implicit flow) , store that in firebase database
4. Return the generated code back to client using redirect uri

Finally , if Authorisation grant flow , you need another cloud functions to handle code exchange to access token

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to create OAuth server. I just want to use already exists one(like facebook/twitter). Any way you mean it is possible.

Comment: I cannot understand... Do I need to use "Cloud Functions"? I think native mobile can do the same thing. I don't know why should I use "Cloud Functions".

Comment: Am sorry , I read your question like you need to implement Oauth server